# string.indexOf() is not working javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why indexOf is not working. 
character "İ" in İstanbul is UTF-8 character but after converting this string to lowercase it looks ok?!

```js
var t = "İstanbul";
var q = "ist";
filterCandidate = t.toLowerCase(); //"istanbul"

var valueToMatch = filterCandidate.trim().substring(0, q.length); //"is"

console.log("filterCandidate: " + filterCandidate);
console.log("valueToMatch: " + valueToMatch);
showElement = false;
if (q.indexOf(valueToMatch) > -1) {
  showElement = true;
  
}
console.log("showElement: " + showElement);
```

Comment: `i` and lowercase `İ` are two different characters.

Answer (score 5):

Lowercase of `İstanbul` is `i̇stanbul` not `istanbul` (Note: difference between `i̇` & `i`).

You told in comment:

> In turkish "I" is "İ" and "i" is "i". This function only works only when I use "İ". Customers may use lowercsae "i" where it is not working

Solution: Use **t.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')** instead of **t.toLowerCase()**.

```
"İstanbul".toLowerCase()                // i̇stanbul 
"İstanbul".toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')   // istanbul
```

```js
var t = "İstanbul";
var q = "ist";
filterCandidate = t.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR'); //"istanbul"
var valueToMatch = filterCandidate.trim().substring(0, q.length);

console.log("filterCandidate: " + filterCandidate);
console.log("valueToMatch: " + valueToMatch);
showElement = false;
if (q.indexOf(valueToMatch) > -1) {
  showElement = true;
  
}
console.log("showElement: " + showElement);
```

Comment: I am building Turkish website, I can't change "İstanbul" to "Istanbul", I need solution for "İstanbul"

Comment: In turkish "I" is "İ" and "i" is "i". This function only works only when I use "İ". Customers may use lowercsae "i" where it is not working

Comment: ok, use `.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')` instead of `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: I appreciate this. It was causing problem when filtering in jsgrid table.

Answer (score 0):

Take care my friend the letter "İ" is not the same the letter "I" some the lowercase of the letter "İ" will never be the same as the letter "I" and the evidence is ....

```
 var t = "İstanbul";
 var q = "ist";
 filterCandidate = t.toLowerCase();
 filterCandidate.toUpperCase(); //this will return "İSTANBUL" again
```

Another evidence is try :-

```
filterCandidate.length // This will return 9 not 8 also the word have only 8 letters.
```

and another try this :-

```
filterCandidate[1] // It will return strange letter "̇"
```

Answer (score 0):

better create a substitute object for holding special character data.

```
var sub = {"İstanbul":"Istanbul"}

var data = "İstanbul";
var t = sub[data]
```

Rest of the code will work accordingly